# how can I make Bixby search treat "season one" equal to "season 1" #devjam

Tags: bixby

I have a template-generated facts capsule where I have tagged some facts with "season one" and "episode two" and so on.

By default, the hint to search on "tell me about season one" works properly, but variations such as "tell me about season 1" or "tell me about the first season" do not.  What do I tweak to make NLU handle these variations properly?

The Javascript search function is:

```
function findContent (items, searchTerm) {
  var matches = []
  searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].tags) {
      for (var j = 0; j < items[i].tags.length; j++) {
        if (searchTerm == items[i].tags[j].toLowerCase()) {
          matches.push(items[i])
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return matches
```

This is a capsule I'm submitting for #devjam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an enum concept that normalizes your inputs using a vocabulary.  For example:

```
enum (Seasons) {

  symbol (Season One)
  symbol (Season Two) 
  // etc

}
```

Then create a vocabulary that handles the variations on how the user may say it.  Let everything resolve to the original symbol you defined:  'Season One', 'Season Two', etc.

```
vocab (Seasons) {
  "Season One" {"season one" "season 1" "first season"}
  "Season Two" {"season two" "season 2" "second season"}
}
```

More info [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/training.vocabulary#vocabulary-for-enumerations)

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I knew there was a way that was better than hacking the Javascript.

Comment: I am not understanding though how this goes with training. What would the training be for goal GetContent and node SearchTerm? I want "Tell me about season one" to pass "Season One" to GetContent as the search term.

Comment: In your training, just tag the enum.  Make sure to train on the variations, so you get solid results.  I've updated the answer with a screenshot of the training.